# Using JSON.NET in Windows Phone to Query One-Time Objects

Tags: windows-phone-8, json.net

I'm working with the Philips Hue API and when I first try to register a username I get the following JSON response back. (My goal is to extract the GUID value of "username" in the "success" object

```
[
   {"error":
      {"type":7,
       "address":"username",
       "description":"invalid value, YourHash, for parameter, username"
      }
   },
   {"success":
      {"username":
       "1234abcd1234abcd1234abcd1234abcd"
      }
   }
]
```

I can't use the dynamic keyword because I'm working in Windows Phone. I don't want to create a "success" class than holds a "username" class that lets me get to this one-time value.

Is there an easy way to traverse this one-time response so that I can simply get the username value?

Answer (score 0):

If you can count on your JSON being in that exact format with no missing information, then you can do something like this:

```
string GetUserName(string json)
{
    return JArray.Parse(json)
        .Children<JObject>()
        .First(o => o["success"] != null)["success"]["username"]
        .ToString();
}
```

Of course this will blow up if there is no object in the result array with a "success" property, or if the "success" property does not contain an object with a "username" property.  If your JSON can deviate from what you've posted above, then you'll need to break this down and add null checks.